# WSDL links in ServiceStack's metadata page are not working

Tags: c#, wsdl, servicestack

I am running servicestack side by side within my ASP.NET webforms application. Every link in the metadata page seems to work except the two WSDL links (soap11, soap12) and the "Request Info" link under Debug Info section. When I click on the WSDL links, I get an invalid xml page that says "Autogenerated WSDLs are not supported with this configuration". When I click on the Request Info link, it throws a stacktrace error as below:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.RequestInfoHandler.ProcessRequest(IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes, String operationName) +1331
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() +109

[AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.]
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +13985681
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait() +17
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +282
```

Here is my Apphost

```
//Tell ServiceStack the name of your application and where to find your services
    public AppHost() : base("Beeline API", typeof(RequestService).Assembly) { }

public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    SetConfig(new HostConfig
    {
        WsdlServiceNamespace = "http://schemas.servicestack.net/types",
        HandlerFactoryPath = "SupplierAPI",
        DebugMode = true
    });
}

public override IServiceRunner<TRequest> CreateServiceRunner<TRequest>(ActionContext actionContext)
{
    return new APIServiceRunner<TRequest>(this, actionContext); //Cached per Service Action
}
```

And here is my Service:

```
    namespace BeelineAPI.Supplier.ServiceInterface
{
    public class RequestService : Service
    {
        public SearchRequestResponse Any(SearchRequest searchRequest)
        {
            return new SearchRequestResponse(){RequestNumber = "1224"};
        }
    }
}
```

And here are my data contracts:

```
    [DataContract(Namespace = Config.WsdlNamespace)]
[Route("/Request/{RequestNumber}")]
public class SearchRequest : IReturn<SearchRequestResponse>
{
    [DataMember]
    public string RequestNumber { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = Config.WsdlNamespace)]
public class SearchRequestResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string RequestNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my web.config as it relates to servicestack:

```
  <location path="SupplierAPI">
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"/>
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>

<!-- Required for IIS 7.0 -->
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers>
    <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory"
         type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"
         preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Glad you resolved your issue. Can you please add your solution as an Answer rather than a comment so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally hooked up my logger to ServiceStack's logging and got the real error: 'Type 'API.Supplier.ServiceModel.CustomFields.Field`1[T]' cannot be exported as a schema type because it is an open generic type. You can only export a generic type if all its generic parameter types are actual types.' WCF cannot serialize to generate the WSDL if your have a property with a type that is generic. In my case it was Field. Need to work around that now. That is why my WSDL links were broken.